# Tomatocart is based on osCommerce - better architecture?

Tags: php, e-commerce

During installation I saw a footer on one of the pages that indicated that Tomatocart is based or built on top of oscommerce.  I've seen many posts on different forums that panned oscommerce.

So is it a good thing that Tomatocart is based on osCommerce?

Anyone with Tomatocart experience can provide some insight?

**UPDATE**
The [about page](http://www.tomatocart.com/about-us/about-tomatocart.html) says that it is a branch of osCommerce 3.

Comment: I wouldn't touch it if the developers are not even ashamed to admit the osCommerce relation.

Comment: If it's based on osCommerce, then run like crazy in the opposite direction.

Comment: everything related to osCommerce should be burned

Comment: I totally agree with above comments. Run away and never turn back!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reviewing many open source ecommerce packages, only a handful are of good quality. Sadly, I do not believe that Tomatocart is one of them.

Despite the many improvements over the infamous OSCommerce, I was very dissapointed to see that they still use a lot of their code, which simply isn't good.

As an example, see the class search.php:
http://code.google.com/p/tomatocart/source/browse/tomatocart/trunk/includes/classes/search.php?r=383

To sum it up, I believe that there are (much) better solutions out there. An alternative would be [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/) or [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/), for example.